# Using LINQ and a dropdownlist to enter a new record into an SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

Hi Everyone I'm a new and I'm struggling with my asp.net website, Our remit is to make a Veterinary Surgery Booking System.

I have an asp.net page that has 4 fields, one of the fields is populated on page load as per the vb code below.

I'm trying to get the selected value (or text) of the dropdownlist control and use it as the value for the first field in the record however every time I select the second or third value in the dropdownlist and click the submit button the new record that is created is inserting the first value in the dropdownlist.

Hope you can help.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.Linq

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim db As New LinQTASK5DataContext
        Dim mu As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
        Dim g As Guid = mu.ProviderUserKey
        Session.Item("uGUID") = g.ToString
        Dim animal = From a In db.pets Where g = a.userGuid Select a.petName
        Dim valSelec = animal
        DropDownList1.DataSource = animal
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
        RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = New DateTime(2100, 1, 1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim db As New LinQTASK5DataContext
        Dim b As New booking With {.petName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, .VetID = cmbVet.Text, .Date = lblDate.Text, .slotID = cmbSlot.Text}
        db.bookings.InsertOnSubmit(b)
        db.SubmitChanges()
        Response.Redirect("~/customers/viewbookings.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the Page_Load function and test for Postback:

```
if not IsPostBack then
   //do your all your  initialization stuff
end if
```

If you don't do that then when you click submit, all of that code runs again and your dropdownlist is getting reset to it's initial value.  The if statement ensures you only do the initialization when the page is first loaded so you get the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You're rebinding the dropdown every time the page loads.  You should encapsulate your binding in an if statement.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
   // your code here
End If
```